Why do 'long' and 'long long' types behave differently when both are 64 bits?
I'm compiling for the x86_64 architecture using Apple Clang (Xcode 14). In the following code:
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

static void foo( long v )
{
    std::cout << v;
}

static void foo( unsigned long v )
{
    std::cout << v;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    static_assert( sizeof(long) == sizeof(long long), "wrong size");
    long i = 3;
    foo( i );
    long long j = 3;
    foo( j );
    return 0;
}

This produces a compile error, pointing to the second call to foo:

error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous

The first call does not produce an error, and the assertion does not fail, verifying that in this case long and long long are both 64-bit (signed) integers.
So, why do these two types behave differently with regard to overload resolution?

Hypothetically, suppose you also defined void foo(long long). Would you expect your compiler to report this as an error (a re-definition of void foo(long)) since both long and long long are 64 bit signed integers on your platform?

The C++ standard simply defines them to be distinct types, that's all.  The fact that they may behave otherwise identically on some implementations is irrelevant to that.  The standard also allows them to be different; e.g. on 32-bit platforms long is usually 32 bits.

If you want types that are guaranteed to be 32-bit and 64-bit, use int32_t, int64_t, etc.  Also, your static_assert error message isn't really a good one -- it should be something like: static_assert( sizeof(long) == sizeof(long long), "application requires long to be same size as long long");.  It really isn't a "wrong size" -- for the compiler, the sizes are correct.

long and long long are ALWAYS distinct types, according to the C++ standard - even if they have EXACTLY the same size and representation on some implementation.  foo() has no overload that accepts long long, so the call foo(j) is required to convert j to a type for which an overload of foo() exists (i.e. either long or unsigned long).  Both those possible conversions are equally suitable hence  the ambiguity.  No rule in the standard requires conversion to long to be preferred on implementations with "identical" representations of long long and long.

Although not really relevant in this specific case, long long and long also have different ranks even if they have the same underlying representation. long and long long are different types in the abstract machine, and rules such as those for overload resolution are also defined on the abstract machine. As others have commented implementation details are irrelevant.

@WeijunZhou  Actually, it is relevant.   The conversion from long long is needed because it has different rank from both long and unsigned long  (even if long and long long happen to be represented identically by an implementation).    And the ambiguity is because long and unsigned long have equal rank.

@Peter. The conversion is needed not because they are of different ranks, but because they are of different types. A conversion is still needed if it were unsigned long long instead of unsigned long, even though unsigned long long does not change the rank. For long long and long which are both signed, having unequal rank is equivalent to not being the same type, so you can state it one way or the other. I do agree that long and unsigned long having the same rank is relevant to the ambiguity.
